# How to remove the DataTable's Row without using loops?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have one datatable which has

DataTable:

```
         SeqNo        ItemID        ItemName
        -------       ------        --------
           1            10           AAA
           2            20           BBB
           3            30           CCC
```

Now I want to remove the Row which has the SeqNo "3".

Now I am doing like this in GridView RowCommand Event:

```
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
        {
            string SeqNo = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
            for (int i = 0; i < DTItem.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (SeqNo == DTItem.Rows[i]["SeqNo"].ToString())
                {
                    DTItem.Rows.Remove(DTItem.Rows[i]);
                }
            }
        }
```

But without loops, How to remove the row based on this condition?

Comment: Why no loops?  Obviously loops will be used at some point - even if it's within the library code you call.  You can't implement an operation on a collection without a loop of some kind at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
DataRow[] rows = DTItem.Select(" SeqNo = " + SeqNo );
rows[0].Delete();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DataRow[] rows = DTItem.Select("SeqNo = " + SeqNo);
foreach (DataRow row in rows) {
    DTItem.Rows.Remove(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that there is only one and definitely one occurrence of the row you can achieve that as following

```
dt1.Rows.Remove(dt1.Select("SeqNo= 3")[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use **DataView** instance.

```
//Set sort key and order
 DTItem.DefaultView.Sort = "SeqNo";
 DTItem.DefaultView.Delete(DTItem.DefaultView.Find(2));
```